# Inner join or condition

Tags: sql

I have table `user` and table `task`. Also i have many-to-many relation between them about can user access the following task or not. Basically table with user_id and task_id fields. I want to get all tasks which user with particular id can access. Seems like simple SQL query with JOIN, however task can have `is_public` field which shows is task public and if so every user can access task. One way I've come to is use `INNER JOIN` and then `UNION`, but the problem is I'm effectively running over the same table two times, if i understood it correctly from other stack questions, one in which i look for all tasks with `is_public = true` and one when I'm using inner join. Is there any way to do it in 1 loop?

Comment: it is always good to provide your sample data and expected output  as that is easier for people to understand

Comment: I don't understand the join if you want to get what tasks a particular user has you can go with : SELECT * FROM  task  WHERE task.is_public = true OR user_id =<userid>

Comment: @supremus . . . A many-to-many relationship would have a third table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select taskId
from task t
left join user u on t.taskId = u.taskId
where t.is_public = 'true' or u.user_id = 'the-user-id-i-want'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.taskId
from task t
where t.is_public = 'true' or
      exists (select 1
              from user_task ut
              where ut.taskid = t.taskid and ut.user_id = ?
             );
```

You *can* express this using a `join`, but it is tricky.  Something like this:

```
select t.taskId
from task t left join
     user_task ut
     on ut.taskid = t.taskid and ut.user_id = ?
where t.is_public = 'true' or ut.taskid is not null;
```